# How can I pass TemporaryUploadedFile to celery task?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, temporary-files

I have a code:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    file = request.FILES["import_file"]
    # create a tast with celery and save ID of the task
    task_id = importing.delay(file).id
    return Response({"task_id": task_id}, content_type="application/json")
```

When type(file) is TemporaryUploadedFile I have errors, because of the file can not be written into redis.

I can take name of this temporary file and save this name into Redis. Then celery worker can get this name from redis and read file. But I am not sure: can the file be deleted before celery worker gets its name from redis?

Comment: File is TEMPORARY and that means, that it can be deleted before celery worker opens it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `TemporaryUploadedFile` is closed and removed as soon as the [`request_finished`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_finished) signal is fired. The file will most likely no longer exist when your Celery worker gets to it.

You should copy the file to a persistent location, and have Celery clean up the file after it is done.

Comment: I have this implemented, I'm copying the uploaded file to new path and passing the path to celery job but celery says file not found, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```py
    def close(self):
        try:
            return self.file.close()
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
                # Means the file was moved or deleted before the tempfile
                # could unlink it.  Still sets self.file.close_called and
                # calls self.file.file.close() before the exception
                raise
```

According to souce code of `close` method of TemporaryUploadedFile, a tempfile will not be closed if it's moved, so you could just move it and pass it's new path to celery task, then delete it yourself when celery task completed.
In this way, you will save your time and resource for copying the file to a persistent location.

```py
    import os
    from django.core.files import uploadedfile

    file = request.FILES["import_file"]
    new_path = '/tmp/import_file'
    if isinstance(file, uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile):
        os.rename(file.file.name, new_path)
    else:    # Deal with InMemoryUploadedFile
        with open(new_path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in file.chunks():
                f.write(chunk)
    task_id = importing.delay(new_path).id
```